# Rand_Max*(max-min)+min << what is that?

Tags: c++, stl, random, c++11, srand

```
generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [=](){return static_cast<T>(static_cast<double>(ran())
/RAND_MAX*(max-min)+min); });
```

Problem: **RAND_MAX*(max-min)+min);**

Ok, so I know the algorithms, lambda expressions, and, capture clause in this thing. My question is quite ridiculous to all of that. What is the bolded text above mean. I mean, I know its part of the random  value generation process. But don't know exactly what the hell is going on. So can someone pls break down that tinny tiny little code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`static_cast<double>(ran())/RAND_MAX*(max-min)+min);`

I'm assuming you mistyped `rand()`, which returns a pseudorandom integer from 0 to RAND_MAX. Let's rewrite that in a way that clarifies the precedence a bit:

`(T) ( (((double) rand() / RAND_MAX) * (max-min) ) + min`

So what it does is:

1. `rand()`: take a random integer between 0 and RAND_MAX
2. `(double) / RAND_MAX`: divide as double by RAND_MAX, yielding a uniformly distributed double between 0 and 1:
3. `* (max-min)`: multiply by the range `(max-min)`, yielding a double from 0 to (max-min)
4. `+min`: add the minimum to yield a random double between min and max
5. `static_cast<T>`: cast it back to the original type

The result is a uniformly distributed random number of type T between `min` and `max`.

Comment: And uniform_*_distribution<T>(min,max) would probably be a better way to do it.

Comment: +1 I didn't want to nag because he just asked what it does, but using the STL would certainly make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `static_cast<double>rand()/RAND_MAX` creates a number between 0.0 and 1.0
When you multiply it by `(max-min)`, you change the range, and when you add to `min` you shift the range. So, after that expression you have a random number (double) that ranges from `min` to `max`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a random function limited on the downside by min (because the rand piece could return zero) and limited to max because even if it returned 100% of max-min, and added to min, you'd be at max

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look at the entire expression: `static_cast<double>(rand())
/RAND_MAX*(max-min)+min)`. Which with explicit grouping looks like: `(static_cast<double>(rand())
/RAND_MAX)*(max-min)+min)`.
The first group returns a random value between 0 & 1 since `rand()` returns a value in the range 0 to RAND_MAX. The second group translates the 0 to 1 range to a `min` to `max` range.

Answer (score 0):

the ran() function returns a random value between min and max ?

but sometimes we need a random value between A and B (min and max). So we can adjust the result for it.

```
a is double, so we use a static_cast! 
a = rand()      ; 0     <=   a   <= RAND_MAX
a = a/RAND_MAX  ; 0     <=   a   <= 1
a = B * a       ; 0     <=   a   <= B
a = min +a      ; 0+min <=   a   <= B+min
```

to produce min <= a <= max,

```
B+min = max
B = max-min
```

in other hands

```
a = rand()/RAND_MAX*(max-min) + min
```

is a random number between min and max.

Comment: `rand()/RAND_MAX` is zero unless `rand() == RAND_MAX`.

Comment: rand() return a integer or a float? I think it is a float. so rand()/RAND_MAX cannot be zero if rand() return something positive.

Comment: `rand()` returns an integer: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Comment: Humm... now I understand the static_cast<double>